# are there possible draw backs when setting 'dbo' to users who have default schema as null?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2016, users, logins

as part of a bigger operation I have been putting together this script below that basically generates a `create user script` for each user of the current database.

When the user has a `default_schema` it comes up in the generated script.

```
   select  permission_order=110
       ,permission_type = 'User Creation'
       ,db = db_name(),
         _login=[master].[sys].[server_principals].[name] collate Latin1_General_CI_AS,
         role_= null,
         obj=null,
        Permission= null,
        [script]=
'USE ' +  quotename(db_name()) + ';' +  CHAR(13) + 
'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from sys.sysusers WHERE name=' +  '''' + [sys].[database_principals].[name] + '''' + ')' + CHAR(13) +
'   CREATE USER ['       
 + [sys].[database_principals].[name] + ']' + ' FOR LOGIN [' + [master].[sys].[server_principals].[name] collate Latin1_General_CI_AS + ']' 
+ CHAR(13) +
ISNULL(' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = '+ QUOTENAME([sys].[database_principals].default_schema_name collate Latin1_General_CI_AS),'') 
+ CHAR(13)         
FROM [sys].[database_principals] 
INNER JOIN [master].[sys].[server_principals]
on [sys].[database_principals].[name] collate Latin1_General_CI_AS =[master].[sys].[server_principals].[name] collate Latin1_General_CI_AS
WHERE [master].[sys].[server_principals].[type] in ('U', 'G', 'S')
```

these lines are examples of a `create user script`:

```
USE [MEME]; IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from sys.sysusers WHERE name='meme')  CREATE USER [meme] FOR LOGIN [meme]  WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo] 
USE [MEME]; IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from sys.sysusers WHERE name='company\Developers')  CREATE USER [company\Developers] FOR LOGIN [company\Developers]
```

Is there anything I should be concerned with, in case I would like to set `dbo` to all my users that currently have their `default_schema` as `null`?

for that end I would use the following script:

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX); 
SET @cmd = N'';
SELECT @cmd = @cmd + N'ALTER USER ' + QUOTENAME(sdp.name) + ' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo];' + CHAR(13) 
 FROM sys.database_principals sdp
INNER JOIN sys.syslogins ss
        ON ss.sid = sdp.sid
 WHERE 1=1
  AND sdp.[type] in ('U', 'G', 'S')  
  AND sdp.default_schema_name IS NULL

PRINT @cmd;
--EXEC sp_executesql @cmd;
```

just to complement, below is a good article about the default_schema of the users, and suggestions as how to change them, however my question here has not been addressed there.

[Script to Set the SQL Server Database Default Schema For All Users](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3098/script-to-set-the-sql-server-database-default-schema-for-all-users/)